# Python - add 1D-array as column of 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add a vector as the first column of my 2D array which looks like :

```
[[  1.     0.     0.      nan]
 [  4.     4.     9.97   1.  ]
 [  4.     4.    27.94   1.  ]
 [  2.     1.     4.17   1.  ]
 [  3.     2.    38.22   1.  ]
 [  4.     4.    31.83   1.  ]
 [  3.     4.    41.87   1.  ]
 [  2.     1.    18.33   1.  ]
 [  4.     4.    33.96   1.  ]
 [  2.     1.     5.65   1.  ]
 [  3.     3.    40.74   1.  ]
 [  2.     1.    10.04   1.  ]
 [  2.     2.    53.15   1.  ]]
```

I want to add an aray [] of 13 elements as the first column of the matrix. I tried with np.stack_column, np.append but it is for 1D vector or doesn't work because I can't chose axis=1 and only do  `np.append(peak_values, results)`

Comment: This is an old post, but for anyone still looking, make [`numpy.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) your friend. Essentially it handles any reshape and stacking operations necessary to combine arrays along their last axis. For the example above, if `arr` is the 2D array and `v` is the vector, all you need is `np.c_[v, arr]`. Note the square brackets.

Comment: Note that is equivalent to `np.hstack((v.reshape(-1,1), arr))` but more powerful because it works in many other cases too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simplest answer, you probably don't even need numpy.

Try the following:

```
new_array = []
new_array.append(your_array)
```

That's it.

Comment: Afterward, you could simply transform this `new_array` into numpy format as you wish, by doing `np.array(new_array)`.

Comment: I don't get where you add the vector. My 2D is array and 1D is vector, I have to do array.append(vector) ?

Comment: Nah don't worry about that. From the start, let's say your array name is `my_2d_array`. We do `my_2d_list = [ ]` and then `my_2d_list.append(my_2d_array)`. Then you got a 2D list with your array as the first column. Finally, please do `my_final_array = np.array(my_2d_list)`, which will transform the python list into numpy array format. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple option for you using numpy -

```
x = np.array( [[ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.942777 , -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767 ,-4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
 [ 3.9427772 ,-4.297677 ]])

b = np.arange(10).reshape(-1,1)
np.concatenate((b.T, x), axis=1)
```

**Output**-

```
array([[ 0.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 1.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 2.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 3.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 4.       ,  3.942777 , -4.297677 ],
       [ 5.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 6.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 7.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 8.       ,  3.9427767, -4.297677 ],
       [ 9.       ,  3.9427772, -4.297677 ]])
```

Comment: This raises `ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 10`. I think you meant `(b, x)` instead of `(b.T, x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54176859/6243352) by removing the unnecessary transposition, you can indeed use `reshape(-1, 1)` to transform the 1d array you'd like to prepend along axis 1 to the 2d array to a 2d array with a single column. At this point, the arrays only differ in shape along the second axis and `np.concatenate` accepts the arguments:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> b = np.arange(3)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> b
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> b.reshape(-1, 1) # preview the reshaping...
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
>>> np.concatenate((b.reshape(-1, 1), a), axis=1)
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using [Numpy](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/). It will allow you to easily do what you want.

Here is an example of squaring the entire set. you can use something like nums[0].

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
even_squares = [x ** 2 for x in nums if x % 2 == 0] 
print even_squares  # Prints "[0, 4, 16]"
```

Comment: I don't understand how squaring a matrix is relevant to the question. The code shown isn't numpy either.